# iOS side bar crash

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, codenameone

Device: any iOS device

Hey guys,

I'm  currently having a problem with the iOS side bar when I try to activate it vy any means (clicking on the three line button or through swiping). The error occurs only on the iOS platform, on any device i've tried (several iPhone 6 running iOS 9 and iPad 1 runing iOS 5). I use the side bar simply by setting the theme constant commandBehavior to Side and just adding the commands to the form. The app freezes completely and I have to force close it.

I attach the stacktrace obtained from one of the iOS devices:

```
    2016-02-10 15:43:08.624 MintDemo[11131:4622381] Deleting thread 3
2016-02-10 15:43:15.395 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:17.507 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:23.086 MintDemo[11131:4622471]

2016-02-10 15:43:23.087 MintDemo[11131:4622471] respuesta value true

2016-02-10 15:43:23.087 MintDemo[11131:4622471]

2016-02-10 15:43:23.128 MintDemo[11131:4622351] WSResult: true

2016-02-10 15:43:23.129 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:23.129 MintDemo[11131:4622351] error msj:null

2016-02-10 15:43:23.130 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:23.130 MintDemo[11131:4622351] notification size: 3

2016-02-10 15:43:23.130 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:59.230 MintDemo[11131:4622351] java.lang.NullPointerException

   at com_codename1_ui_Label.paint:461

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1287

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Form.paint:3033

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Form.internalPaintImpl:3043

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1210

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintComponent:1488

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintComponent:1439

   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty:504

   at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1072

   at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:994

   at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120

   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176

   at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153

2016-02-10 15:43:59.231 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:59.263 MintDemo[11131:4622351] java.lang.NullPointerException

   at com_codename1_ui_Label.paint:461

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1287

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Container.paint:1290

   at com_codename1_ui_Form.paint:3033

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.internalPaintImpl:1293

   at com_codename1_ui_Form.internalPaintImpl:3043

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternalImpl:1267

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1242

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintInternal:1210

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintComponent:1488

   at com_codename1_ui_Component.paintComponent:1439

   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneImplementation.paintDirty:504

   at com_codename1_ui_Display.edtLoopImpl:1072

   at com_codename1_ui_Display.flushEdt:881

   at com_codename1_ui_Form.showModal:1695

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showModal:1021

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:492

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPackedImpl:1323

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showPacked:1231

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.showImpl:977

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:955

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:913

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:702

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:655

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:620

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:562

   at com_codename1_ui_Dialog.show:716

   at com_codename1_ui_Display.mainEDTLoop:1007

   at com_codename1_ui_RunnableWrapper.run:120

   at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176

   at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153

2016-02-10 15:43:59.263 MintDemo[11131:4622351]

2016-02-10 15:43:59.264 MintDemo[11131:4622351] [EDT] 0:0:0,1 - java.lang.NullPointerException: null

2016-02-10 15:43:59.280 MintDemo[11131:4622351] [EDT] 0:0:0,17 - java.lang.NullPointerException: null

2016-02-10 15:43:59.296 MintDemo[11131:4622351] Deleting thread 2

MintDemo >
```

Hope this is enough to determine a probable cause to this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some details about the components you have within the sidebar? How do you add commands to there? If you have a standalone test case I can use to reproduce the issue that would be very helpful!

Comment: Hey Shai, 

thanks for your response. I'm only adding commands with a commandId and Image (taken from the resource file)  

Image icon = fetchResourceFile().getImage("round-profile-pic.png");
f.addCommand(new Command(null, icon));

Comment: Aditionally, I set the "commandBehavior" constant to "Side"on the Codename One Designer. 

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the:

```
f.addCommand(new Command(null, icon));
```

Changing this to:

```
f.addCommand(new Command("", icon));
```

Produces the same result while working around the bug. We've added a fix for this in the code which will be a part of the next server update.